# Python SST tests never fail

Tags: python, selenium, tdd

I've just started looking at [SST](http://testutils.org/sst/index.html) this morning. I've written this simple test case, which always passes:

```
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases

class RootTest(cases.SSTTestCase):
    def test_root_page(self):
        go_to('http://localhost:8888/')
        assert_title_contains('Booga')
        assert_button("file_select")
        assert_button("upload")
        return self


class LoginTest(cases.SSTTestCase):
    def login(self):
        go_to('http://localhost:8888/login')
        assert_element(id="Email")
        assert_element(id="Passwd")
        assert_element(id="booga")
        return self
```

There are no 'booga's in my code.

When I do sst-run sst_test I get the following:

```
Tests running...
    DEBUG:SST:Starting browser (attempt: 1)
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 5392 with port: 32773, count 1
    DEBUG:SST:Cannot connect to process 5392 with port: 32773, count 2
    DEBUG:SST:Browser started: firefox
    DEBUG:SST:Stopping browser
sst_test ... OK (2.317 secs)

Ran 1 test in 2.317s
OK
```

It's an ubuntu 12.04 system with py 2.7.3. Why aren't the tests failing?

Comment: BTW -- SST doesn't appear to actually be hitting the server running at localhost.

Comment: Have you tried running with `python -m unittest your_tests.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use your own runner.  `sst-run` is for running SST's script-based tests only.

see:
http://testutils.org/sst/#using-sst-in-unittest-test-suites

Comment: <blushing> Thanks! </blushing>